# image scaling is not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am working on a simple HTML website, and faced a problem. Logos like Twitter or LinkedIn are not being scaled in Internet Explorer (it is the latest version)-- but other browsers work fine. Here is a fragment of my code:

```
<td>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<;url>">
<img src="images/linkedin.gif" height="28" width="28" border="0"/>
```

What can I do to scale those images in Internet Explorer?

Comment: can you add a paste of your code? it might be a doctype problem or invalid syntax in the html document.

Comment: I think syntax is valid-- it works fine in Chrome or firefox. and the DOCTYPE is html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<img src="images/linkedin.gif" style="height:28px; width:28px; border:none;"/>`

and if this fails 
try adding `!important` behind all styles

may be something overrides your style

Answer (score 1):

At least when working with HTML5, I found that Internet Explorer seems to interpret width and height parameters on the img tag as crop sizes. To get a properly scaled image, you need to enclose it in a figure tag like this:

```
<figure style="width: 28; height: 28; margin: 0">
    <img src="images/linkedin.gif" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%"/>
</figure>
```

This will also work fine in other browsers.

Comment: this worked for me, thank you so much. Banging my head on a wall for hours on this.